# Spring Boot & Elastic Search | Multi-index search functionality

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a spring boot API which has three models (User, Projects, Skills) currently I can search any of the indexes without issue as below:

```
  log.info("Search with query {}", query);
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder =
                QueryBuilders
                        .multiMatchQuery(query, "projectDescription", "projectName", "projectTechStack")
                        .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE);

        Query searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withFilter(queryBuilder)
                .withPageable(pageable)
                .build();

        SearchHits<UserProjects> projectHits =
                elasticsearchOperations
                        .search(searchQuery, UserProjects.class,
                                IndexCoordinates.of(elasticProjectsIndex));
```

However I would like to search all three indices and map them to the correct POJO. I'm rather stuck on this. Furthermore and this is where I get VERY stuck is, I would like to have a response paginated which would contain lets say the following:

```
User results: 3 of 100 
Project Results 4 of 10
etc etc
```

Basically so on my front end I can know if I should show a "click here for more User results" link which would run a search just on the user index.

If anyone can please help me that would be amazing.

Thanks

Comment: It makes more sense to have 3 separate APIs, which will call respective query respective indices.

Comment: May I ask why do you think that? Surely that what the MultiSeachResponse is for? If lets say you check out LinkedIn search and search for Java, you'll see a mix of people, jobs, course etc. Then you can click view more on each of those which will call a separate endpoint, thats what I'm looking to try and do. Thank you for taking the time though.

Comment: Got better clarity of your requirements with your comment .. thanks. It makes sense

Comment: Try https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-multi-search.html.   Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you I think this is exactly what I was looking for. If you want add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct. thank you again for your time

Comment: Sure i will add it as an answer. It will help other folks as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user wants to search across multiple dimensions/indexes then [MultiSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) will be very useful.

**Example Usage:** User can search for 'java' in person, article & job indices (in a LinkedIn type application) and would be able to configure pagination per request.