# Elasticsearch - unify search results from different indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform a search query on different indexes with different search queries and unify the results.
I know there is a [multi-target syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html), which allows me to perform specific query over multiple indexes.

What I want is different query for each index and then perform something like UNION (SQL).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Check this out "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67512304/spring-boot-elastic-search-multi-index-search-functionality?noredirect=1#comment119371939_67512304" ...

Comment: All the indices has overlapping data points ? May i know what is the use case.. so that i can help better

Comment: @SahilGupta  There is several overlapping data points across all the indices. 
I want to unify the results over the date, which would result to sth like news feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`_index`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html) metadata field. This will help you to query on multiple indexes with different queries

Adding a working example with index data, search query and search result

**Index Data**

```
POST /index1/_doc/1
{
  "name":"foo"
}

POST /index2/_doc/1
{
  "name":"bar"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": "foo"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "index1"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "name": "bar"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "index2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.287682,
        "_source": {
          "name": "foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "index2",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.287682,
        "_source": {
          "name": "bar"
        }
      }
    ]
```